# Parallel for loop over entries of an array without sharing it with all the workers

Tags: julia

I am working with big data arrays, something of order of 10^10 elements. I fill the entries of these arrays by calling a certain function. All entries are independent so I would like to make use of this and fill the array simultaneously by a parallel for loop that runs over a set of indices and calls the function. I know about SharedArrays and this how I usually implement such thing but because I am using huge arrays, I don't want to share them over all the workers. I want to keep my array only on the main worker and then execute a parallel for loops and transferring the result of each loop to the main worker to be stored in the array.

For example, this is what I normally do for small arrays.

```
H = SharedArray{ComplexF64}(n,n) #creates a shared array of size n*n
@sync @distributed for i in 1:q 
    H[i] = f(i) #f is a function defined on every worker
end
```

The problem with such construction is that if the size of the array n is too big, sharing it with all the workers is not very efficient. Is there a way of getting around this? I realize my question might be very naive and I apologize for this.

Comment: I don't really do paralles stuff, but isn't this the exact use case for [DistributedArrays](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/DistributedArrays.jl)?

Answer (score 1):

A `SharedArray` is not copied among workers! It simply allows the same memory area to be accessible by all processes. This is indeed very fast because there is no communication overhead between the workers. The master process can simply *look* at the memory area filled by workers and that's it.

The *only* disadvantage of the `SharedArrays` is that all workers in to be on the same host. If using `DistributedArrays` you only add unnecessary allocations due to the inter-process communication because each worker is holding only its own part of the array.

Let us have a look (these are two equivalent codes for shared and distributed arrays):

```
using Distributed
using BenchmarkTools
addprocs(4)
using SharedArrays
function f1()
    h = SharedArray{Float64}(10_000) #creates a shared array of size n*n
    @sync @distributed for i in 1:10_000
        h[i] = sum(rand(1_000))
    end
    h
end

using DistributedArrays
@everywhere using DistributedArrays
function f2()
    d = dzeros(10_000) #creates a shared array of size n*n
    @sync @distributed for i in 1:10_000
        p = localpart(d)
        p[((i-1) % 2500)+1] = sum(rand(1_000))
    end
    d
end
```

Now the benchamrks:

```
julia> @btime f1();
7.151 ms (1032 allocations: 42.97 KiB)

julia> @btime(sum(f1()));
7.168 ms (1022 allocations: 42.81 KiB)


julia> @btime f2();
7.110 ms (1057 allocations: 42.14 KiB)

julia> @btime sum(f2());
7.405 ms (1407 allocations: 55.95 KiB)
```

Conclusion:

on a single machine the execution times are approximately equal, but collecting the data by the master node adds a significant number of memory allocations when `DistributedArrays` are used. Hence, on a single machine you always want to go for `SharedArrays` (moreover the API is simpler as well).